# VBA text loop optimisation - Extract emails from text

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, optimization

I need a bit of help with a small project. I just started VBA and I think I could use learning to optimise my code.

Cell A2, contains a text with many email address separated by ",". I managed to extract all the email addresses but I think I made too much use of cells, and I was wondering if you can help me reduce that and use the variables defined instead. 
[Screenshot of the working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbDH9.png)

```
 Sub fpor()
Dim Text As String
Dim full As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim part As String
Dim part_len As Integer
Dim part_a As Integer
Dim Text_2 As String
x = 5

        ActiveCell = Range("A2")
        Text = Range("A2")
        full = Len(Text)
        'full = InStrRev(Text, ",")

                 For i = 1 To full

                        Cells((x + i), 1).Value = Text
                        part = InStr(Text, ",")
                        Cells((x + i), 2).Value = part
                        Cells((x + i), 3) = Left(Text, part)
                        Cells((x + i), 4) = full - part
                        Text = Right(Cells((x + i), 1), Cells((x + i), 4))

                            If part = 0 Then
                                full = 0
                                Cells((x + i), 3) = Text
                                Exit For
                            Else:
                                full = Len(Text)
                            End If

                    Next i

       MsgBox (full)
       MsgBox (part)

     End Sub `
```

How do you think I can better optimise the For Loop?

Thank you all for your answers you awesome people  : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can greatly simplify your code with the use of [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528(v=office.15).aspx) Function as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fpor()
    Dim emailsArr As Variant

    With Worksheets("emails") '<--change "emails" with your actual sheet name
        emailsArr = Split(.Range("a2"), ",") '<--| split all emails names delimited by a ',' into an array
        .Range("A6").Resize(UBound(emailsArr)).value = Application.Transpose(emailsArr) '<--| write array content from cell A6 downwards
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's powerful. 
Thank you kindly user3598756 ; ) 

That code is wicked.